# Null-coalescing assignment operator in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to create a null-coalescing assignment operator in Swift 3. In other words, instead of this:

```
x = x ?? y
```

I want this:

```
x ??= y
```

Swift 3 does not seem to like my operator. Here's its definition:

```
infix operator ??= : AssignmentPrecedence
func ??=(lhs: inout Any?, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Any?) {
    if lhs != nil { return }
    lhs = rhs()
}
var x = 3
x ??= 7 // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'inout Any?'.
```

I've done it without the `@autoclosure` too. My understanding is that the precedence group `AssignmentPrecedence` already contains the `assignment` declaration, so this is unlikely to be the problem.

How can I do this in Swift 3?

Comment: You may need to note [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md), when discussing about this topic.

Comment: Very good point, but it appears you've already noted it. :)

Comment: Surely, so, I also note that, when I proposed something very similar to `ClosedRange` in the era of Swift 1.x in the old Apple's dev forums, the response from Swift team was sort of cold and negative. But, as you see, now Swift 3 have it. Swift 5 would have this operator in the Standard Library if we can appeal its use cases well enough.

Comment: Its use case can be summed up in two words: syntactic efficiency. It's strange to me that Swift makes such strong use of optionals but does not have this kind of assigment operator.

Comment: +1 for it. But this is not a good place to appeal to Swift team. Maybe we developers should visit swift.org more often, and express developers opinions. I would not blame anybody if Swift 3.1 has this operator in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make the operator generic instead of using `Any`:

```
infix operator ??= : AssignmentPrecedence
func ??=<T>(lhs: inout T?, rhs: @autoclosure () -> T?) {
    if lhs != nil { return }
    lhs = rhs()
}
```

Second, the left operand needs to be an optional (otherwise it
could not be tested against `nil`):

```
var x: Int? = 3
x ??= 7
```

Comment: Actually, I knew this. Very stupid of me. Still, I hope this helps someone out in the future.

Comment: I'm deeply surprised this operator is not included in the Swift standard library by default. It seems so obvious to have it.

Comment: Note that an inout parameter is copied into the function and then copied back on return (subject to compiler optimisation). So even if the lhs is not nil, it will be assigned a new value, and property observers are called. This makes the operator less useful than one might think.

Comment: While it may be less computationally efficient, it is definitely more syntactically efficient. I can live with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I came up with my own 'flavor' of a null-coalescing assignment operator, similar to the above, but by adding a return type, you can both do assignment and return at the same time which is more in line with normal '??' behavior, with the addition of the assignment from the RHS to the LHS if LHS is null.  It's perfect for resettable lazy vars.  Here's my version...

```swift
// Null-coalescing assignment operator
infix operator ??= : AssignmentPrecedence
@discardableResult
func ??= <T>(lhs: inout T?, rhs: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {

    if let lhs {
        return lhs
    }

    let rhsResult = rhs()

    lhs = rhsResult

    return rhsResult
}
```

With the above, I can now do resettable lazy vars like this...

```swift
private var qCache:Int?
var q:Int {
    return qCache ??= {
        print("Lazy-calculating q...")
        return 44
    }()
}
func resetQ() { qCache = nil }

print("1: q is \(q)")
print("2: q is \(q)")
print("3: q is \(q)")

print("Resetting lazy q...")
resetQ()

print("4: q is \(q)")
```

Output...

```
Lazy-calculating q...
1: q is 44
2: q is 44
3: q is 44
Resetting lazy q...
Lazy-calculating q...
4: q is 44
```

You can also implement the setter too, if you wish as well as separating out the 'lazy calc' function...

```swift
func lazyCalcQ() -> Int {
    print("Lazy-calculating q...")
    return 44
}    

private var qCache:Int?
var q:Int {
    get { return qCache ??= lazyCalcQ() }
    set { qCache = newValue }
}
func resetQ() { qCache = nil }
```

Going a step further, you can use implicitly-unwrapped datatypes so you can use the assignment of `nil` to be the reset, yet you are always guaranteed a value from the getter. The only down-side is you still sometimes have to force-unwrap it to silence some warnings like in the print statements below, but again, you are guaranteed a value, so it's safe to do.

> *Note: Personally I prefer the approach above with the non-implicitly-unwrapped version and the extra 'reset' function--especially if it's a read-only property--because it makes the API much clearer, but I'm sharing this for completeness since it shows a creative use for nil-as-reset.*

```swift
func lazyCalcR() -> Int {
    print("Lazy-calculating r (i.e. the default when reset with 'nil')...")
    return 10
}

private var rCache:Int?
var r:Int! {
    get { return rCache ??= lazyCalcR() }
    set { rCache = newValue }
}

print("1: r is \(r!)")
r += 10
print("2: r is \(r!)")
r += 10
print("3: r is \(r!)")

print("Resetting r to default...")
r = nil

print("4: r is \(r!)")
```

Output...

```
Lazy-calculating r (i.e. the default when reset with 'nil')...
1: r is 10
2: r is 20
3: r is 30
Resetting r to default...
Lazy-calculating r (i.e. the default when reset with 'nil')...
4: r is 10
```

Of course the above are all trivial examples using an int, but I use it to do things like calculating complex paths based on bounds, etc.

My next attempt will be to hide all of this in property wrappers, eliminating the need for this operator itself.